# .htaccess subdomain Rewrite rule is not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I am making a website builder an I would like to make urls prettier.

The url would be for example:

`https://ccc-bb.example.com` => `https://example.com/project/show/ccc/bb`

This is my **.htaccess** file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
# prevents files starting with dot to be viewed by browser
RewriteRule /\.|^\.(?!well-known/) - [F]

# front controller
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\-(.*)$ https://example.com/project/show/$1/$2 [L]
```

When I use above (`https://ccc-bb.example.com`) it sends me to the subdomain empty folder. The folder has only the .htaccess file.

[image: empty subdomain folder]

What am I missing? I've never edited an .htaccess file and Google didn't help me (or I don't know what should I looking for).

Answer (score 0):

Your first rule for dotfiles is okay but would be better the other way around, since the second part can only match the start, but the first can only match in subdirectories.

```
RewriteRule ^\.(?!well-known/)|/\. - [F]
```

Your other rule's problem is that you are expecting it to match the subdomain. `RewriteRule`s do not operate on the entire string you see in your browser's address bar, only the path part, and in `.htaccess` they see even less as the leading directory is stripped off, too. To access the info you want, use a `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^-]++)-([^-.]++)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(?!project/show/).* project/show/%1/%2/$0 [L,DPI]
```

(You don't need to include `\.example\.com$` if your main domain contains no hyphens.)